# Why did I get blank (empty) content when I used async setup() in Vue.js 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

**Problem**

I use `async setup()` in Vue.js 3, but I got my HTML content to disappear. My component template did not insert to HTML, but when I remove the async and await prefix, my HTML content comes back. How can I fix this?

```javascript
async setup () {
    const data = ref(null)
    try {
        const res = await fetch('api')
        data.value = res.json()
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
    return {
        data
    }
}
```

**I've tried**

1. I checked fetch, and it returned the correct response
2. I've tried `<Suspense>` tag, but still the same problem

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Your component's `async setup()` looks fine other than the missing `await res.json()`, which still wouldn't cause the problem you're seeing. I suspect your usage of `<Suspense>` is incorrect.

To use `async setup()` in a component, the parent component must use that component in a `<Suspense>` tag:

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<template>
 <Suspense>
   <MyAsyncComponent />
 </Suspense>
</template>
```

You could also use the `default` and `fallback` slots of `<Suspense>` to show a loading indicator while waiting for the child component's setup to resolve:

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<template>
 <Suspense>
   <template #default>
     <MyAsyncComponent />
   </template>
   <template #fallback>
     <span>Loading...</span>
   </template>
 </Suspense>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-async-setup?file=src/App.vue)

Answer (score 5):

#### File *parent.vue*

```html
<template>
  <!-- parent add <suspense> -->
  <suspense>
    <child />
  </suspense>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './child.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    child
  },
  setup() {
    return {}
  }
}
</script>
```

#### File *child.vue*

```html
<template>
  <div>child</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async setup() {
    return {}
  }
}
</script>
```

For `child.vue`, use `async setup...`. For `parent.vue`, you need to add `<suspense>` to `child.vue`.