# I got blank when use async setup() in Vue3 with router-view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

When I use `async setup ()` in Vue 3, my component disappears. I used the solution found here:
[why i got blank when use async setup() in Vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64009348/why-i-got-blank-when-use-async-setup-in-vue3/64266335#64266335) ... it worked, but I have a blank page when I am using the `router-view`.

```html
<template>
    <div v-if="error">{{error}}</div>
    <Suspense>
        <template #default>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </template>
        <template #fallback>
            <Loading />
        </template>
    </Suspense>
</template>

<script>
import Loading from "./components/Loading"
import { ref, onErrorCaptured } from "vue"

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: { Loading },
    setup() {
        const error = ref(null)
        onErrorCaptured(e => {
            error.value = e
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

*main.js:*

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from "./router"
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

When I replace `router-view` with one of my components, it shows up.

*Router:*

```js
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Portfolio from "@/views/Portfolio.vue";
import Blog from "@/views/Blog/Blog.vue";
import Detail from "@/views/Blog/Detail.vue";
import NotFound from "@/views/NotFound.vue";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Portfolio,
    },
    {
        path: "/blog",
        name: "blog",
        component: Blog,
    },
    {
        path: "/blog/:slug",
        name: "detail",
        component: Detail,
    },
    {
        path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
        component: NotFound,
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});


export default router;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<Suspense>`'s default template should contain an *async component* (i.e., one with `async setup()`), but you've put `<router-view>` in there instead.

You'd have to refactor the `<Suspense>` into its own wrapper component (e.g., `HomeView.vue`) that contains the async component, leaving `<router-view>` itself in `App`:

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<!-- HomeView.vue -->
<template>
  <Suspense>
    <template #default>
      <MyAsyncComponent />
    </template>
    <template #fallback>
      <Loading />
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>
```

Then update your router config to use that wrapper:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/'
    name: 'Home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  //...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue doc has an example to show how to use `<Suspense>` with other components

```html
<RouterView v-slot="{ Component }">
  <template v-if="Component">
    <Transition mode="out-in">
      <KeepAlive>
        <Suspense>
          <!-- main content -->
          <component :is="Component"></component>

          <!-- loading state -->
          <template #fallback>
            Loading...
          </template>
        </Suspense>
      </KeepAlive>
    </Transition>
  </template>
</RouterView>
```

Ref: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#combining-with-other-components